# Socket Communication not reaching server

Tags: java, sockets

I have the following code to (attempt to) write to a server:

```
    String serverName = "w.x.y.z"; 
    int port = 3010;

    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverName);

    Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress, port);

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    bufferedWriter.write(transactionString);
    bufferedWriter.write(headerString);
    bufferedWriter.write(loginString);
    bufferedWriter.flush();

    String result = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String str;
    while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(str + "\n");
    }
    result = new String(sb);
    debug("done with reads");

    textArea.setText(new String(result));
}
catch (UnknownHostException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have a breakpoint in the server code on the remote machine, and I have a Visual Basic program that communicates over this same socket.  I have run the Visual Basic code and (repeatedly) verified that the server is there, listening on this socket, and that I can hit my breakpoint by running that program.

I do not hit the breakpoint when I run this program.  I have tried various things about setting up the socket, such as instantiating the socket with just "new Socket()" and setting the inetAddress and port number with setter methods afterwards.  I have used OutputStreamWriter instead of BufferedWriter.  I have tried this with KeepAlive set false and timeout set to 15 seconds.  None of it causes the server to hit its breakpoint.

I get the following output.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
```

and of course many more stackTrace lines.

It is not a data formatting issue; the breakpoint should be hit as soon as the server hears a message on that port, before it has a chance to figure out whether it is valid.  It is not a matter of the server working, since it works at this port and socket from the other program.  I have triple-checked the address and port number between the two; I don't think there can be any problem there.

It is not a reading issue of any sort; as I said, the breakpoint on the mainframe is not hit.

I set a breakpoint after the call to getByName(), opened inetAddress in the debugger, found the 4-byte int that represented the IP address, and translated each hex byte -- after translating from the domain name, has the same IP address that I get from pinging the server from the machine where I'm running all this.

Can someone suggest where else I might look?

Comment: What does the network traffic look like if you run [wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) while trying your code? An unrelated thought: you've got a needless `new String(result)` near the end.

Comment: Eventually you should be writing new lines or some sort of separators between the strings you initially write. In any case, it is possible that a firewall might be blocking your connection. You should try and check if you can ping the desired server, and if you can establish a console connection at the desired port to make sure the problem is not in the network configuration itself. Hope that helps.

Comment: @serrano - this makes no difference to my problem.  Nothing at all is getting to the server.  As I stated, not only can I ping it (and did), but another program running on the same machine can reach the server.

Comment: Strange indeed. What does isBound(), isClosed(), isConnected() on the socket right after you get it show?

Comment: Hm, personally I would write one byte at a time on the socket outputstream. (I assume you have quadruple checked that transactionString etc is correct). There might be a character encoding problem. Otherwise I'm kinda out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: you should include the context of the server code where you set the breakpoint. Anyway since the problem is the client, you should carefully debug it and tell how it terminates (or what function call makes it wait forever)

Comment: @esej thanks for the effort.  In fact, it does not matter at all what those strings have in them, because they're never reaching the server at all.  I suppose I could try writing a byte or two, but anything written should cause a byte to show up there, and it isn't happening now.

Comment: Actually, what is the output on the client side? Unless it gets locked on bufferedReader.readLine() it should produce some output.

Comment: editing the original message to show the output.

Comment: When posting a stack trace one should also tell which line throws the exception. Anyway we can argue that the point when you read the response is reached, so the problem really is on the server side or in your application custom protocol. For example, can you ensure that transaction, header and login are separated by a new line character if your server blocks until a new line is sent? Can you post your server code?

Comment: Yeah, with this new information we are on a new track. You should be able to debug this. I suggest first sending one byte, and making sure it reaches the server-side, then sending one character (in java that is sometimes a totally different thing), then one line.

Comment: The line which throws the exception is port read.  I will include it when I get back to that computer.  The server is hundreds, maybe a thousand or two, lines of COBOL code that is not mine to post.  It has not been changed in years and works fine if I send a message from another program, written in Visual Basic 6.  It makes no difference whether I send one byte or multiple lines or one protocol or another, please read the above again -- not a single byte reaches the server.  Not one.  *I* think the evidence says the port is not set up correctly.  But why?

Comment: A dozen comments, and if you can't post the server code this question will never found its answer :) We can't help if we can't reproduce, just guessing, and it's the long way find the bug. Why are you so sure that no packet gets to the server? Can you describe your *debug* procedure? What if you connect with telnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the server required an SSL socket.  Thanks to those that responded.

Comment: you should at least tell how you debugged the issue. Stackoverflow is not yet another forum. Your experience could help other users diagnose the same issue

Comment: I realized the other server required an SSL socket.  The other code I had was using an SSL socket, and I should have remembered that the server required SSL.  It wasn't really a debugging issue, though Sharkwire did tell me the receiving IP did receive something.  But I didn't know how to read anything else it was telling me.  I'm afraid there isn't much about the experience that is going to help anyone else debug anything.